# Is "using animations" idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language, idiom-request

Is "using an animation" idiomatic? I think it's the most idiomatic way to say that a character in a video game has a particular animation, but I am wondering if it's really the case, or there's a much better way to say it.

For example:

> The dog used the animations of the cat instead of having its own
>   animations.

Comment: by "animation" do you mean a certain gesture/action, or the entire digital rendering of the dog as a cat?

Comment: animation like in a video game.

Comment: The way its phrased now sounds like there is a character that is supposed to be a dog, but is "drawn" by the computer graphics as looking like the cat character that is also in the game. Is that what you intend to mean?

Comment: No, the dog is using the animations of a cat.

Comment: Could you say it in a way that doesn't use the word animation? I am not sure exactly what you mean by it. Do you mean something like Fortnite's [dances and emotes](https://progameguides.com/fortnite-dances-and-emotes-list/)?

Comment: By ruling out *gestures*, *actions*, and *appearance* as a way of describing what you mean by *animation*, you've left nothing understandable. If you mean to use the word *animation* in a way that doesn't mean any of those things, you need to provide a definition of it. You can't just repeat the word. The problem is that we don't understand what you mean by it—if it's none of those things you've rejected.

Comment: @blackbird I've got a way for you to clear this up: does the dog look like a cat, or does it look like a dog, only performing the actions that the cat usually performs?